# Gauge Invariance for the Klein Gordon Equation

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-invariance, klein-gordon-equation

Maybe it's the four vector notation that is throwing me off, but can someone explain why after substituting the primed quantities in and applying the four-momentum to the phase term the four momentum term still exists?

[image: Page from RQM by Wachter]

Comment: Which step in the derivation you felt confused with?

Comment: @JamieBondi getting to equation 1.8

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question. It seems like a pretty standard derivation. What do you mean by the momentum term still existing? What would you expect to happen to it? Could you explain a little more what you think should happen so we know where you're getting stuck?

In the meantime, do you know that the operator $\hat{p}$ is defined in position space as a *derivative* $$\hat{p}_\mu = i\hbar\partial_\mu$$

Thus, $$\hat{p}_\mu (e^{-i\Lambda}\phi') = e^{-i\Lambda}(\hat{p}_\mu + \hbar\partial_\mu\Lambda) \phi'$$

Comment: @PhilipCherian I didn't even distribute in the phi prime term in the first line in the derivation which is set equal to zero. I distributed the exponential term into the brackets and applied the momentum operator to the exponential term, which would give you the second term in the parentheses that you wrote down on the bottom. My question is why does the momentum operator term exist after you apply it to the exponential term?

Comment: @PhilipCherian Is my problem that I applied only the phase term to the momentum operator and not the phase term and the phi prime term at the same time?

Comment: Right, I might have misunderstood your question, but I think your problem stems from acting the momentum operator *separately* on the exponential and on $\phi'$. That isn't allowed mathematically. In equation 1.8, the operator in the parentheses acts on $e^{-i\Lambda}\phi'$ *together*, which means you must use the chain rule as indicated in my earlier comment.

Comment: @PhilipCherian Thank you. I knew i was doing something dumb.

Comment: Not a problem at all, it wasn't too long ago that I was doing the same thing! However, I would really advise you to read up on [using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/448779), since it would make your posts much more readable and I suspect people would be more inclined to help you if they see that you've taken the time to write things out clearly.